# Language symbols generators list

Tags: discussion

A lot of conlangs use custom symbols/alphabet. One of languages designed by me does this too. Because it might be hard to locate generators for some less famous conlangs, we can link all of them here (in answers)!

This might be useful for placing text in the language on the site itself, if the generator supports exporting as image.

If there is a tag defined for a specific language, you can use it in your answer, by adding `[tag:language-name]`, so it's easier to search  for it.

Comment: Should be make it one tag per answer, or one generator per answer? Also, should we allow links to iconic fonts for specific languages?

Comment: My gut feeling is that each answer should be one _language_, with however many generators are found for that language (and obviously editable/updatable when new ones are found/written). The problem that arises is that a language _name_ may not be unique - so if I tag a set of generators [tag:elvish], how do I know whether we're talking about an elvish written by Tolkien, Brooks, or Potrzebie?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin there was a discussion about this. Don't use [tag:elvish], use [tag:tolkien-elvish].

Comment: so tags should be of the form `tag:creator-language` when there's the possibility of confusion? (I note that "Elvish" is the most likely source of problems, but can see this happening with languages from just about any fantasy race)

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Yes, [here is the discussion btw](https://conlang.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18/8)

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Incidentally, the proposed list would seem to be one sort of resource that [this metaquestion](https://conlang.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55/should-we-maintain-a-list-of-conlanging-resources-on-meta) would apply to.