# Should we maintain a list of conlanging resources on meta?

Tags: discussion

The question of resources to refer to, for beginners or any other level, is going to come up at some point. Would it be a good use of time to maintain a list of them here, so that users could have a one stop shop area to refer to? Or would that be out of scope?

Answer (score 12):

I might actually want to argue that the list of resources is better kept *on the main site.* Precedence for this:

- [Resources for learning chemistry on Chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37303)
- [Resources for learning German on German.SE](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/9526)
- [Resources for learning Russian on Russian.SE](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/833)
- and others

They do all seem to follow the same format. We may choose to do so or do differently, that should probably be discussed on meta. But I think the actual resources question should be on main for larger visibility.

Comment: See also Robert Cartaino's answer here which says Meta is not a good way to deal with resource questions: https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/a/142/9

Answer (score 3):

**I think this is a good idea.**

Other sites maintain a meta repository of resources like this without problems. For example:

- [Literature SE](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/652/17)
- [Puzzling SE](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4921/5373)

Meta is a good place to do it for a couple of reasons.

- On most sites at least, "big list" questions usually get closed as too broad. Meta tends to be more liberal - we even have a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag, despite SE's general strong aversion to "discussiony" type content! - and this is reflected in the [help centre](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). The general rule is that pretty much anything goes if it's relevant to the site concerned, until and unless it starts causing problems. I can't think of any problems that a single canonical resources list on meta would cause.
- Meta has a (low) bar to participation. One of the problems with big-list questions on the main site is that anyone can come along and add a new answer which might potentially be just as valid as all the others. On meta, people normally have more sense and/or experience with the system.

Comment: I've seen in other stacks that a question - on the main site - can be 'protected', requiring some amount of rep earned on the site before additional answers can be submitted, and in such cases, the association bonus doesn't count. Perhaps that should be the model for a conlang.se resource list?

Comment: An example of such a question - I see them quite often in [politics.se] - is [this one](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/28371/why-is-a-big-country-less-suitable-for-high-tax-high-welfare-system).

Answer (score -1):

I don't think long resource lists are a good fit for the Stack Exchange format. I've never found any of them useful. Especially because they often duplicate information found in wikis - they could be a lot of work for extremely minimal gain.

It's better to ask a specific and well-defined question on the main site, and get tailored information in the answers.